# View inside stored procedure using SQL Sever 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I created a view for each month but this is for the present month only. I'm trying to find a way where I can make it dynamic. I have this view which is being called by a stored procedure but it seems I'm missing something.

Here's my script for view

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'december_permonth_view')
   DROP VIEW december_permonth_view   <--range from Jan to dec
GO

CREATE VIEW december_permonth_view  <--range from Jan to dec
AS 
   SELECT *
   FROM TblGPSCur 
   WHERE PHILTIME BETWEEN '2014-12-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-12-31 23:59:59.000'  <--dont know how to make it dynamic
GO
```

Now here's my stored procedure which calls the view stated above

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcessByMonth
   @from_date datetime , 
   @to_date datetime 
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @month AS INT
   SET @month = (SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()))

   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF @month = '1'
   BEGIN
      SELECT * january_permonth_view
   END

   IF @month = '2'
   BEGIN
     SELECT * february_permonth_view
   END

   IF @month = '3'
   BEGIN
      SELECT * march_permonth_view
   END

   IF @month = '4'
   BEGIN
      SELECT * april_permonth_view
    END
IF @month = '5'
BEGIN
SELECT * may_permonth_view
END
IF @month = '6'
BEGIN
SELECT * june_permonth_view
END
IF @month = '7'
BEGIN
SELECT * july_permonth_view
END
IF @month = '8'
BEGIN
SELECT * august_permonth_view
END
IF @month = '9'
BEGIN
SELECT * september_permonth_view
END
IF @month = '10'
BEGIN
SELECT * october_permonth_view
END
IF @month = '11'
BEGIN
SELECT * november_permonth_view
END
IF @month = '12'
BEGIN
SELECT * december_permonth_view
END
END
GO
```

Can someone help me where I went wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Waaaaay to many views! You're overcomplicating the whole thing....

Answer (score 1):

What's the deal with all those views? Instead of creating soooo many views...isn't it much simpler to just create a stored procedure that takes in a date range (two `date`s...NOT `datetime`s) and execute a select statement that filters the result set for that date range?

```
create procedure ProcessByMonth
    @from_date datetime , 
    @to_date datetime 
as
begin
    select * from TblGPSCur where PHILTIME between @from_date and @to_date;
end
go
```

that's all you need. No need to over-engineer the whole thing

Comment: +1 absolutely. Or if, for some reason, there has to be a view - at least create **one view** with a `Month` column so the select becomes: `SELECT * yearview WHERE month = @month` instead of having 12 separate views....